# How to change eav attribute label only in loaded product?

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute

I'm loading a product from a model.
And this product has some attributes like color, size etc.
My problem is that the labels of the color attribute have some extra informations divided by pipes.
Some day we will clean this mess up but for now I'm trying to load the product and change/crop the color labels only for that product and return it to $this.

Is this possible and how?
At the moment I can get all color attributes in a foreach loop but I don't know how to save then in my loaded product.